# account problems (Geometry Dash)

Tags: geometry-dash

I'm having trouble with my account for Geometry Dash. When I check my profile, it says "Something went wrong..." but when I click refresh, it doesn't change.

Comment: Is this on the website, or in the game itself?

Comment: To solve this you should probably contact the support for Geometry Dash.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem. I honestly don't really care because the only thing I use it for is my stats, which I can check from the character editor. EDIT: Maybe it's because the servers are so slow, that's been a problem for a while since 2.1 came out

Comment: I had this problem too, I think it is because of changing something in your account, like changing passwords.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to me, was to close the game and reopen it. It can be unstabble wifi connection too, that was my friend's case.

Answer (score 0):

Bad wifi could be it, I have the same problem but it definitely isn't wifi, it is probably either you updated your account, their is server maintenance, or, like me, it is just something going on with the game itself affecting the account files

Answer (score -2):

Refresh the account.  Go to Options --> Acount --> More --> Refresh Login,
and you solve the problem.